# Dissolving polygons by attribute within certain distance using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, buffer, dissolve

In a FeatureClass I have a lot of polygons which contain attributes of different landuse-types.

Now I am trying to dissolve those polygons of the same landuse-type, but only if the distance between them is less than 100m.

I'm trying this with ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 (ArcInfo level license).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution, it's not the best, because it's a little bit complicated but in the ModelBuilder, it will work:

1. Aggregate Polygons tool with a distance tolerance of 100m.
2. Spatial Join (one to many; within) to associate the aggregated polygon IDs with their input polygons.
3. Dissolve based on the JOIN_FID (=Aggregate ID) to dissolve the input polygons by the aggregated polygon IDs (Multipart).
4. ... for every landuse type.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in a few steps in ArcGIS.

1. Perform a [Select By Attribute](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000021000000) to select all features with a specific land use type (e.g. residential).
2. Perform a [Select By Location](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s50000002q000000) on the previous selection with a 100m tolerance specified.
3. Run the [Dissolve](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000005n000000) tool on the final selection.

This can be done manually if you only have a few land use types, or you could use the model builder.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer!
But this approach does not work, because after step 2 the selection still contains all polygons of the selected landuse type. But even if only those were selected that are close to each other, the selected would all be dissolved. Not only each of those that are in close to each other.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried a different method. I was doing a land use map to develop a dynamic land use map, and at the end I had a lot of polygons too small. I defined the mimimum area as 90,000 square meters (9 hectares) because of the publication scale map.

Here are the steps to eliminate those too small polygons:

1. Open the attribute table and sort the polygons by size using square meters, miles etc...
2. Select the polygons that you know that are too small to be presented at the publication scale map.
3. Open the Arc Toolbox and tap on the Index "Eliminate (management)"
4. Set the Input Layer and Output Layer and tap on the "Ok" button.

I hope it helped you. Sorry I can not set images by now, mailme if you want

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum.Please go though http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer.Please do not share your e-mail id.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. You've described how to remove small polygons from the data.